# AppEngine bulkloader export Model with self-defined Property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I want to use **bulkloader** to download all entities in a model with *some self-defined Property*.

If I define a model like this,

```
class MyType:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.name = arg['name']
        self.id = arg['id']

class MyProperty(db.Property):
    def get_value_for_datastore(self, instance):
        val = super(MyProperty, self).get_value_for_datastore(instance)
        if type(val) == dict:
            val = MyType(val)
        return pickle.dumps(val)

    def make_value_from_datastore(self, val):
        return None if val is None else pickle.loads(str(val))

class MyModel(db.Model):
    info = MyProperty()
```

then how can I download `MyModel` using the bulkloader such that *there will not be un-pickled value in the file*? I think I should define the `export_transform` for `info` in bulkloader.yaml, but I don't know what it should be like.

```
transformers:
- kind: MyModel
  connector: csv
  property_map:
  - property: __key__
    external_name: log_id
    export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
  - property: info
    external_name: info
    export_transform: ### HERE ###
```

I've seen [transform.py](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py&q=transform%20package%3ahttp://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com) but still have no idea about how it works. Please tell my any method that can solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "such that there will not be un-pickled value in the file"? Do you not want that field to show up, or do you want it there pickled, or something else?

Comment: What I want to say is, I want that field to show in the CSV, but I want it to be unpickled before being written to the CSV. Currently the field will show in the CSV as a pickled value.

Comment: An unpickled string is an object. You can't output an object to a text file, only a string representation of it. What representation do you want to write to the file?

Comment: If using the above example, I want to know if I can write `info.name` or `info.name,info.id` to the field "info" in the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'm answering my own questions...

I still don't know why `pickle` doesn't work, but after changing to use `simplejson` instead of `pickle`, I can successfully export `MyProperty` in the designated format.

The bulkloader.yaml may look like this.

```
python_preamable:
- import myutils
- import django.utils.simplejson
...

transformers:
- kind: MyModel
  connector: csv
  property_map:
  ...
  - property: info
    external_name: info
    export_transform: myutils.load_info
```

And in myutils.py `load_info` may look like this.

```
def load_info():
    def load(x):
        if not x:
            return ''
        info = simplejson.loads(x)
        return '%s-%s' % (info['id'], info['name']) # the output format for info
    return load
```