# Google App Engine: Error in bulkloader.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently trying to download and exports tables from a Google App that I inherited. I am using their Python Framework. 
Here are the relevant lines in the bulkloader.yaml file:

```
- kind: KindName
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    encoding: utf-8
    print_export_header_row: true

  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
    - property: field1
      external_name: field1
    - property: keyInAnotherTable
      external_name: keyInAnotherTable
      import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(transform.create_foreign_key('AnotherTable'))
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

Then when I run the buklloader, I first must wait over an hour for everything to download, and then finally it finishes with this error:

```
google.appengine.ext.bulkload.bulkloader_errors.ErrorOnTransform: Error on transform.
Property: keyInAnotherTable External Name: keyInAnotherTable. Code: 
transform.key_id_or_name_as_string Details: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'to_path'
```

I can't seem to find any relevant information via Googling.

Thanks in advance.

**Also** Is there any way to export straight from the downloaded sql3 file into CSV so that I don't have to download so many times?

Comment: I would actually really like to know as well.

Comment: hmmm. I still can't find anything on Google, except for my own post here haha

Comment: I tried all the methods like create_deep_key(), create_foreign_key(), join_list(), none_if_empty() but all result in exporting but crashing at the end.

Comment: @skurt yeah I never resolved this but instead just ported all the code into my existing system/language then re-acquired all the data I could myself

Comment: argh, this sounds as a noop, I will ask in https://developers.google.com/appengine/community?hl=de and mention the bounty

Comment: @skurt please do post back here if you resolve it. I'd still be interested.

Comment: I have found the solution with these postings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697357/appengine-bulkloader-export-model-with-self-defined-property

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out. The data we were exporting was so huge that it consistently took over an hour every time just to find out if it worked or not haha. I'll give this a try

Comment: Maybe you can run "appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config" and compare your yaml with generated one to find potential error. Reference https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata?hl=en#Using_Automatic_Configuration

Answer (score 2):

This question deserves an answer (as contributed by @skurt, @Robert Lujo, @Kenny Cason).

Have a read of the following references to assist with resolving issue with bulkloader failing after an hour:

- [AppEngine bulkloader export Model with self-defined Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697357/appengine-bulkloader-export-model-with-self-defined-property)
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata?hl=en#Using_Automatic_Configuration